# How to fetch values likes PDO::FETCH_COLUMN in Doctrine?

Tags: pdo, doctrine-orm

I have the following code:

```
$repository = $this->entitymanager->getRepository('Intlist\Entity\Location');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('l')
    ->select('l.country')
    ->groupBy('l.country')
    ->where('l.country != :empty_country')
    ->setParameter('empty_country', "")
    ->getQuery();
```

And I would like to obtain something like `[ 'EN', 'FR', 'US' ]`, like `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` would return. I tried `getScalarResult()` but it returns the same result as `getArrayResult()`:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'country' => string 'DE' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'country' => string 'MM' (length=2)
```

I tried to use `execute()` as I have seen on some examples but it returns the same result as `getArrayResult()` and not a PDO statement.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello this possibility was added in Doctrine ORM 2.10+ you can now do (following your example) :

```php
$repository = $this->entitymanager->getRepository('Intlist\Entity\Location');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('l')
    ->select('l.country')
    ->groupBy('l.country')
    ->where('l.country != :empty_country')
    ->setParameter('empty_country', "")
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleColumnResult();
```

References :

- Documentation : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.10/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#scalar-column-hydration
- Merge request : https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/8919/files

Answer (score 3):

You can extract values from your query result to get the array you want :

```
$repository = $this->entitymanager->getRepository('Intlist\Entity\Location');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('l')
    ->select('l.country')
    ->groupBy('l.country')
    ->where('l.country != :empty_country')
    ->setParameter('empty_country', "")
    ->getScalarResult();

$country_codes = array();
foreach($query as $result){
    $country_codes[] = $result['country'];
}
```

If you want native results, you can make a custom hydration mode, [as explained in Doctrine doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes).

Create a class extending AbstractHydrator:

```
namespace MyProject\Hydrators;

use Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\AbstractHydrator;

class ColumnHydrator extends AbstractHydrator
{
    protected function _hydrateAll()
    {
        return $this->_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    }
}
```

Add the class to the ORM configuration:

```
$em->getConfiguration()->addCustomHydrationMode('ColumnHydrator', 'MyProject\Hydrators\ColumnHydrator');
```

Then use it:

```
$repository = $this->entitymanager->getRepository('Intlist\Entity\Location');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('l')
    ->select('l.country')
    ->groupBy('l.country')
    ->where('l.country != :empty_country')
    ->setParameter('empty_country', "")
    ->getQuery();
$results = $query->getResult('ColumnHydrator');
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that I'm looking for a native function, like `PDO::fetchAll()` with `\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`, I don't want to parse the result.

Comment: @olvlvl did you got the time to take a look at my edit?

Comment: Thanks @Veve, looks good. Too bad this hydrator is not packed with Doctrine.